# DataTables Not Working With ASP.NET GridView

Tags: css, asp.net, gridview, datatables

I'm using Gridview to display Data from SQL in my content page and I've added all the references related to jQuery DataTables but unfortunately it's not working. All I get is a Gridview with bootstrap styling in it. below is my ASPX Markup:

```html
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
    <!-- DataTables -->
  <link href="plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</asp:Content>
<div class="box-body" style="overflow:scroll; height:200px">
                            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" CssClass="table table-bordered table-striped" runat="server" CellPadding="5" CellSpacing="2">
                                <Columns>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sl. No.">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <%#Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                </Columns>
                            </asp:GridView>
                    </div>
<script src="plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   <script>
       $(function () {
           $("#GridView1").DataTable();({      
               "paging": true,
               "lengthChange": false,
               "searching": false,
               "ordering": true,
               "info": true,
               "autoWidth": false               
           });
       })
</script>           
</asp:Content>
```

Kindly help me!

Comment: Why are you mixing GridView and Datatable, both are two different component. For data table you just need a div and data to bind

Comment: Did you ever get this to work?
 I know this is marked as duplicate, however, the recommended answers do not address the row CSS classes that are completely ignored.
The paging/sorting work just fine (and the buttons are formatted as well), but something in the GridView control prevents this (striping of the odd/even rows for example).  The order of the CSS reference makes no difference (and clearly the javascript works).

Comment: Yes I got it working luckily!